# Control of a nonlinear static MIMO System

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, nonlinear-control

I am currently writing my master thesis and trying to design a controller for my system. However, the system is somewhat unconventional.

It has a large number of inputs and outputs, is static, non-linear and time-invariant. The goal is to control the disturbance. Because it is static, conventional controllers for MIMO systems (NMPC etc.) are only of limited use.

At the moment I am looking for a similar system in another area.
Does anyone have an idea in which area such a system exist?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by static system?

Comment: @JoshPilipovsky That I assume that the system is so fast that I only have a nonlinear input output mapping. The problems are more the disturbances. I somehow have to control them.

Comment: So your I/O is something like $Y(s) = \phi(s)$, where $\phi$ is the nonlinearity right? Are the disturbances delta functions then, since they are so fast?

Comment: @JoshPilipovsky Yeah, that is how my function looks like. Actually, it looks like this $F_{x,y}^{(h)} = a^{(h)}
e^{-
    \frac{(x-x_{a})^{2} + (y-y_{a})^{2}}
    {b^{(h)}}
}$ Where $x_{a}$ and $y_{a}$ is my input for one h (I have ~1000 of h). $(x,y)$ is my measurement point (where I have ~1000 as well). $a$ and $b$ are just parameters. I could reduce the problem though to a size of 100x100.

One disturbance is rather static. The other is dynamic and I am not even sure how to model it.

Comment: Maybe it would be good if you included some extra information about the system. For example, a mathematical model (I suppose you have one) and if you have any info regarding the nonlinearities.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, it seems like you are trying to control a dynamical system to track some reference trajectory subject to Gaussian disturbances. Suppose you have some kind of model for the dynamics, then the discrete system can be written as

$$
\begin{align}
x_{k+1} &= f_k(x_k) + a_k w_k\\
y_k &= x_k
\end{align}
$$

where $w_k$ is a Gaussian vector with mean $\mu_k = [x_a^{(k)}, y_a^{(k)}]^\intercal$ and covariance $\Sigma_{x_k} = \frac{b^{(k)}}{2} I_2$. 
This is then a stochastic Control problem and there are various methods to create a stabilizing controller just check out the literature.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will have a look. Though, I have one disturbances which is not stochastic and very strong. It causes that the outputs of some variables h fade partly or completely. Is stochastic control still a solution then?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many systems similar to your system.

A very common way to write a system with a nonlinearty is by writing it as Luré Type System, where the nonlinearity is in the feedback loop
$$ \begin{align}
\dot{x}(t) &= Ax(t) +Bw(t)\\
z(t) &= Cx + Dw(t)\\
w(t) &= \Delta(t,z)
\end{align}$$
where $\Delta$ is the nonlinearty.

Depending on the type of nonlinearty, you can apply all kinds of controller synthesis such as $H_\infty$, $H_2$ and QP.

For example, you can create a sector condition for the nonlinearty and use the Circle Criterion to check if the system is absolutely stable.
A common nonlinearty to use in this framework is a saturation.